# "There are alot of people who can substitute you"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, grammaticality

Is "There are alot of people who can substitute you" equivalent to
"There are alot of people who can substitute for you".(People will take your position).

I reckon if we use "substitute" without "for" in my given example then it will be wrong and we could only use "replace" without "for" and the right sentence will be "There are alot of people who can replace you".

Anyhow I need your recommendation, whether there should always be "for" or whether we can omit "for" and the meaning will remain same for "substitute"(in my given example).

Comment: Your first sentence can be understood as "There are a lot of people who can substitute you [for something else unspecified]" (although that isn't really idiomatic), while your second sentence would mean "There are a lot of people who can substitute [themselves] for you."

Comment: It's **a lot**, not *alot*.  See http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html

Comment: Yes, it's two words "a" + "lot".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great answer, Esther.

- To substitute: commit the act of replacing
- To substitute for: be the replacement